# How do I implement a custom SQL aggregate or comparator function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions, comparator

Given the following table, I need to produce a result showing the availability for a selected range.  The rule of availability dictates an order of X,?,'',Y.  For example, given the following dataset:

```
+------------+--------------+------+
| date       | availability | id   |
+------------+--------------+------+
| 2015-09-01 | X            |    1 |
| 2015-09-02 | X            |    1 |
| 2015-09-03 | X            |    1 |
| 2015-09-04 | X            |    1 |
| 2015-09-01 | X            |    2 |
| 2015-09-02 | ?            |    2 |
| 2015-09-03 | X            |    2 |
| 2015-09-04 | X            |    2 |
| 2015-09-01 | ''           |    3 |
| 2015-09-02 | Y            |    3 |
| 2015-09-03 | Y            |    3 |
| 2015-09-04 | Y            |    4 |
| 2015-09-01 | Y            |    4 |
| 2015-09-02 | Y            |    4 |
| 2015-09-03 | Y            |    4 |
| 2015-09-04 | Y            |    4 |
+------------+--------------+------+
```

my desired output would be:

```
+--------------+------+
| availability | id   |
+--------------+------+
| X            |    1 |
| ?            |    2 |
| ''           |    3 |
| Y            |    4 |
+--------------+------+
```

I know if I was dealing with numerical values, I could possibly use `MIN` `MAX` etc. My question is, does SQL give me an easy way to define a custom aggregate or comparator function to implement this logic?

I'm using Azure SQL if different vendors have different solutions for this.

Comment: I'm not perfectly sure I understand the question, but I think I can help. Are you just trying to eliminate duplicates in the availability / id columns in your returned result set?

Answer (score 2):

Just use prioritization logic:

```
select ids.id, a.availability
from (select distinct id from table t) ids cross apply
     (select top 1 availability
      from table t2
      where t2.id = t.id
      order by (case when availability = 'X' then 1
                     when availability = '?' then 2
                     when availability = '' then 3
                     when availability = 'Y' then 4
                     else 5
                end)
     ) a;
```

If you have a separate table of ids, then you should use that instead of the subquery.

There are other approaches; however, the ones I can readily think of require more complex `case` statements, two joins, or more complex SQL.  You don't need a "custom aggregation".  You just need to figure out how to prioritize the results.

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't accepted Gordon's answer, I will answer this question more directly:

> My question is, does SQL give me an easy way to define a custom
>   aggregate or comparator function to implement this logic?

No, it does not.